# Git shows differences in files, but won't merge them

Tags: git, merge, diff

I'm kind of stumped here.  Git appears is both telling me that

1. There are differences between my current branch and the remote branch, and
2. There are no differences between my current branch and the remote branch

One of these is a lie (or more likely, I'm misunderstanding this scenario).  What's up with this??

```
(~/hbb.vm) debian $ git diff ..stage/master --name-only
sites/all/libraries/attachment_email/attachment_email.php
sites/all/modules/redirect/redirect.module
sites/all/modules/redirect/redirect.test
sites/all/themes/HBB/css/elements.css
sites/all/themes/HBB/templates/node--enterprise_blog.tpl.php

(~/hbb.vm) debian $ git merge stage/master
Already up-to-date.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The merge command is telling you that your current branch contains all of the 
commits from the `stage/master` branch, but not the reverse.  It is likely that 
your current branch contains changes which aren't in `stage/master` and it is 
those changes which are being reflected in your diff command.

```
 a-b----c
    \
     d--e
```

With the above repository if I have `e` checked out, trying to merge `b` will 
correctly state that things are up to date.  But asking for differences between 
my current state and that same point, it's likely that differences will be 
present (not guaranteed, `e` could revert the changes from `d` or both `e` and 
`d` could be empty commits).

BTW, your diff command is somewhat incorrect. The `..` in front of the branch 
name causes that to be interpreted as a range of commits (equivalent to 
`HEAD..stage/master`), but diff operates on individual commits rather than 
ranges. This is a somewhat common mistake so diff has been adjusted to somewhat 
allow for it, but it can still give misleading results. In this case it will 
show changes reversed from what you'd likely expect showing the changes needed 
to go from your current state to `stage/master` rather than the changes that 
took place to bring the state from `stage/master` to the state reflected by the 
tip of your current branch. The latter is more likely be be what you were 
expecting.

Comment: Is there a way to `git diff` that shows a little more information? Like whether the file has been deleted or modified and which branches it is located in?

Comment: @doub1ejack: That would be better asked as a new question. That will likely get it more attention and could be answered better that way than in comments.

Comment: It's true, I was being lazy. [Sorry about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996220/looking-for-more-info-from-my-git-diff-command).  I have another [question open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996531/why-cant-i-do-git-diff-on-this-specific-commit) about your point on `..branch_name`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in assuming 1.: There're differences between where you're at (`HEAD`) and `stage/master`.

Any of these tell you this:

1. `git diff ..stage/master`
2. `git diff HEAD..stage/master`
3. `git diff stage/master..`
4. `git diff stage/master..HEAD`

1 is short-hand for 2, and 3 for 4.  3 is just the reverse diff of 1.

`git diff stage/master` that @qqx mentioned will further tell you of any differences between your working-tree and `stage/master`.  (Compared to 1 or 3, you'll also see uncommitted changes.)

You're incorrect in thinking 2.: There are no differences between `HEAD` and `stage/master`.

Rather, `git merge stage/master` is telling you that there're no commits in `stage/master` that aren't already in (or merged to) `HEAD`.

This might also tell you this:

- `git log ...stage/master --cherry-pick`

And this might tell you of the commits that're causing the diff after you've merged `stage/master`:

- `git log stage/master... --cherry-pick`