# Why can't I do git diff on this specific commit?

Tags: git, diff

This works fine:

```
[git@hbhriq]$ git diff ..ers-gr-patch --name-only
sites/all/modules/brd_form_alters/brd_form_alters.module
sites/all/modules/brd_social/brd_social.module
sites/all/modules/globalredirect/globalredirect.module
```

But @qqx points out in [one of my other recent posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955286/git-shows-differences-in-files-but-wont-merge-them/17955603?noredirect=1#comment26246718_17955603) that using `..erg-gr-patch` is not really the right way to do things.  Unfortunately, the alternative fails:

```
[git@hbhriq]$ git diff ers-gr-patch --name-only
error: bad tree object ers-gr-patch
```

@qqx said the following about `..branch_name`:

> BTW, your diff command is somewhat incorrect. The .. in front of the
>   branch name causes that to be interpreted as a range of commits
>   (equivalent to HEAD..stage/master), but diff operates on individual
>   commits rather than ranges. This is a somewhat common mistake so diff
>   has been adjusted to somewhat allow for it, but it can still give
>   misleading results. In this case it will show changes reversed from
>   what you'd likely expect showing the changes needed to go from your
>   current state to stage/master rather than the changes that took place
>   to bring the state from stage/master to the state reflected by the tip
>   of your current branch. The latter is more likely be be what you were
>   expecting.

Can someone help me understand what the problem is?

Comment: What do `git rev-parse ers-gr-patch` and `git cat-file -t ers-gr-patch` output?

Comment: rats. that branch has been merged & deleted by now so I can't give you any more info. sorry.